# Android/Kotlin RoomDataBase perform Action on Insert

Tags: android, database, kotlin

On Android RoomDatabase, I would like to perform an action when an object is inserted in database and get the Id of the saved data.
In Kotlin i have this code:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(note: Note)
```

I search to do something like that but that doesn't work:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(note: Note){ 
Log.v("tag", "Id: " + note.id)
}
```

Do you think it's possible ?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: rename it to `insertInernal` (eventualy made it protected)  then made `fun insert(note: Note) {Log.v("tag", "Id: " + note.id)  insertInternal(note)}`

Comment: I don't understand your answer, i want to perform an action and get the id of the inserted data when it's saved

Comment: Before edit there was no info that you wana get id of inserted note  ... so I thought that tou wana add some log statment inside insert method

Comment: Yes that's why i have edited, my sentence was unclear ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert will return the id of the inserted record

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(note: Note): Long
```

Then you can use as so

```
Log.v("tag", "Id: " + insert(note))
```